# Highlight yanked region during sequence of yank-pop's until mark is moved away

Tags: yank

I sometimes find myself yanking a large chunk `C-y` and then cycling `M-y` through some previous kills. This can feel visually noisy to me, i.e. during the sequence of replaces it's easy to lose track of the boundary between what was just yanked and text that was previously in the buffer.

I think what I want to do is highlight the yanked region somehow for the duration of the yank-pops until point moves away. Is that implemented somewhere as a standard feature already?

**Expanded description**:
Let me try to phrase what I'm after another way. The region of text just inserted into a buffer by C-y should be highlighted so it's clear where its boundary is. The highlight should remain for any M-y's that follow and adjust itself to surround whatever the newly popped text is. When point moves and M-y is no longer possible, the highlight should disappear.

Comment: Highlight the region that got yanked or highlight the text where it was yanked? It's not clear to me what you want or why the highlighting would help with the problem you describe.

Comment: Please edit the question to include all such description. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [volatile-highlights.el](https://github.com/k-talo/volatile-highlights.el) package

> which brings visual feedback to some operations by highlighting portions relating to the operations.

including `yank` and `yank-pop`.

Also advice on `insert-for-yank` may help. See [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/8qyq53/can_i_make_emacs_highlight_the_area_that_i_just/e0otw43) for example and inspiration.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.